# 3 arguments turned into a 2-tuple

Tags: python, function, tuples, arguments

> Define a function named generate_point which takes 3 arguments (i.e. 2 numbers and a 6-tuple), and returns a
> 2-tuple.
> Ex. Given inputs: ,  and c0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 the function shall calculate and return 1 and 1 respectively as
> follows:
> 1 = 0 + 1 + 2
> 1 = 3 + 4 + 5

I was given the shell for generate_point as

```
def generate_point(x, y, cff) -> tuple:
   pass
```

I'm not sure where to go from here to begin inputs to form a 2-tuple.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unpack your input tuple, and then just return exactly what the prompt says.

You can unpack your 6-tuple like this:

```
c0, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 = cff
```

Comment: Don't do the OP's homework for them.